# How to create a postgresql query to update column values?

Tags: postgresql

I have table named map_info which has two columns namely map_id (int) and is_map_applied(boolean). I am giving single map_id and TRUE value to is_map_applied column. I also want to set all values of column is_map_applied to FALSE except row which has requested map_id irrespective of their previous values. What may be the query?

Comment: Please take a few minutes and edit your question by adding sample data.

Answer (score 0):

```
update map_info set is_map_applied = (map_id = 2);
```

Set `is_map_applied` to `true` for row with specified id, set `is_map_applied` to `false` for rows with different id.